# Dynamic linking in Python CFFI?

Tags: python, dynamic-linking, python-cffi

I'm trying to use CFFI for dynamic linking of dependent C libraries in Python; am I mis-understanding it?

In the following extremely simplified example, library `foo_b` depends on library `foo_a`. Specifically, it depends on `bar`, and it exposes its own function `baz`.

```py
from cffi import FFI
from pathlib import Path

Path('foo_a.h').write_text("""\
int bar(int x);
""")
Path('foo_a.c').write_text("""\
#include "foo_a.h"
int bar(int x) {
  return x + 69;
}
""")

Path('foo_b.h').write_text("""\
int baz(int x);
""")
Path('foo_b.c').write_text("""\
#include "foo_a.h"
#include "foo_b.h"
int baz(int x) {
  return bar(x * 100);
}
""")

ffi_a = FFI()
ffi_b = FFI()

ffi_a.cdef('int bar(int x);')
ffi_a.set_source('ffi_foo_a', '#include "foo_a.h"', sources=['foo_a.c'])
ffi_a.compile()

ffi_b.cdef('int baz(int x);')
ffi_b.include(ffi_a)
ffi_b.set_source('ffi_foo_b', '#include "foo_b.h"', sources=['foo_b.c'])
ffi_b.compile()

import ffi_foo_a
if ffi_foo_a.lib.bar(1) == 70: print('foo_a OK')
else: raise AssertionError('foo_a ERR')

import ffi_foo_b  # Crashes on _this_ line due to undefined symbol "bar", DESPITE the fact that we included ffi_a, which should provide that symbol
if ffi_foo_b.lib.baz(420) == 42069: print('foo_b OK')
else: raise AssertionError('foo_b ERR')
```

However, it doesn't compile, instead crashing on the indicated line with the indicated error message.

I don't understand why this example isn't working, considering the following in the CFFI documentation:

> For out-of-line modules, the `ffibuilder.include(other_ffibuilder)` line should occur in the build script, and the `other_ffibuilder` argument should be another FFI instance that comes from another build script. When the two build scripts are turned into generated files, say `_ffi.so` and `_other_ffi.so`, then importing `_ffi.so` will internally cause `_other_ffi.so` to be imported. At that point, the real declarations from `_other_ffi.so` are combined with the real declarations from `_ffi.so`.

If ffibuilder.include() isn't the right way to dynamically link together multiple CFFI-based libraries, what is?

Or if ffibuilder.include() *is* the right way to dynamically link together multiple CFFI-based libraries, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The library `ffi_foo_b.cpython-XXX.so` fails to import because of the C-level issue that it doesn't find the symbol `bar`.  Looking at the tests in CFFI, it seems that this case is not supported: the `ffi_foo_b.include(ffi_foo_a)` syntax is not enough to cause the C-level `ffi_foo_b.cpython-XXX.so` to be compiled specially.  If a symbol from `ffi_foo_a.cpython-XXX.so` is needed *at the C level* for `ffi_foo_b.cpython-XXX.so` to load, then it won't work.  The CFFI documentation is kinda misleading.  It means rather that, say, you can take things like `struct` type definitions that appear in `ffi_a` and use them from `lib_foo_b.ffi`.

In terms of CFFI implementation, I'm not quite sure how this case could be supported: for example, on Windows you need special tricks to export a symbol from a DLL (with the extension `.dll` or `.pyd` for CPython extension modules).  In other words your example on Windows produces a `ffi_foo_a` that doesn't automatically export `bar` at all at the level of C.  You can still call `ffi_foo_a.bar()`, because the look up of `bar` inside `ffi_foo_a` is done at a different level (on any platform) than the raw C level.  You could also call it as `ffi_foo_b.bar()` thanks to the `ffi.include()`, if there wasn't the problem that `ffi_foo_b` tries to use `bar` at the C level directly.  But you can't use the C symbol `bar` from `foo_b.set_source()`.

For now I'd recommend one of these solutions:

1. consolidating everything inside a single `ffi`.
2. make standard, CFFI- and Python-independant `.so` as you need them, e.g. `foo_a.so` and `foo_b.so`, with the proper C-level Makefile or something, with `foo_b` compiled in such a way to say that it depends on `foo_a`---using some gcc arguments like `-L . -lfoo_a.so`.  Then you can wrap these two `.so` with two CFFI libraries.  You can use `ffi.include()` then; this is really how `ffi.include()` was meant to work.
3. as a mixture of 1 and 2, you can probably have `foo_a.so` compiled as a standalone module, and then wrapped in `ffi_a`, but keep the existing solution for `ffi_b` because no symbol from `ffi_b` is expected to be found at the C level from somewhere else.

**EDIT:** two more possible solutions:

4. You can probably have it working just like you wrote, but you need to add platform- and compiler-specific options.  I'd not recommend that option.
5. You can bypass the problem by not calling `bar()` from `foo_b.c`.  Instead, you'd write code like this:

   ```
    Path('foo_b.c').write_text("""\
    #include "foo_b.h"
    static int (*_glob_bar)(int);  // global variable
    int baz(int x) {
      return _glob_bar(x * 100);
    }
    """)

    ffi_b.cdef("""
        int (*_glob_bar)(int);
        int baz(int x);
    """)
   ```

   This removes the dependency at the C level.  You need
   to initialize the global variable once after import:

   ```
    import ffi_foo_b
    ffi_foo_b.lib._glob_bar =
        ffi_foo_a.ffi.addressof(ffi_foo_a.lib, "bar")
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Just to be clear, your suggestion `1` refers to regular static linking, baking the copy of *foo\_a* into *foo\_b*? (As for `3`, I don't actually need to expose any of *foo\_a* to the Python consumer; it's only a vendored C implementation of some common hash functions.)

Comment: I'll look into `2` more; I'm trying to make my library easy to compile cross-platform, though, and in my  case *foo\_a*'s source code is actually [shipped with *foo\_b*'s source code](https://github.com/PQClean/PQClean/blob/0657749a785db30e7f49e9435452cb042edb1852/crypto_kem/mceliece6960119f/clean/crypto_hash.h#L4), rather than being a library the user is going to be able to find in apt or dnf, so if I can get it compiled with setuptools and distributed with pip with the rest of the library, that would be a huge advantage.

Comment: If both foo_a and foo_b come from the same source and you always want to use together, then yes, I'd suggest to try the solution `1`.  Write a single `ffi` that exposes all the functions that you need from both; and write a single `ffi.set_source(..., sources=[..all_c_files_from_both_libraries..])`.

Comment: In this case, there are around **33** different "b" libraries this package will provide—all depending on the same "a" library—so this seemed like a natural situation for dynamic linking. You suggest (`4`) that it would only take a few platform-specific changes to get *ffibuilder.include()* working for this; what would those changes be? I already have added in my build scripts codepaths to inject platform-specific changes, due to [issues with MSVC name mangling](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/175js2u/comment/k4qit36/), so it might not be a large imposition to add more.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too familiar with MSVC, but it's harder on Windows because you need to explicitly declare which symbols must be exported from DLLs (or .pyd files for CPython, which are really DLLs).  Use google, but again I wouldn't go down that path---for example, it's likely to only work for CPython+MSVC, but not PyPy, etc.  I would either stick all 34 libraries into a single ffi, or package the `a` library into something usable from C (i.e. a real DLL) and then write 34 ffi's: one for that DLL if you need it from Python, and 33 where you compile the code with `set_source` like you're doing.

Comment: In other words, the question starts with "how would you do it in C, if Python was not involved".  In that case you'd likely have 34 DLLs, generated using specific MSVC parameters or Visual Studio configurations to set up the export/import symbols correctly.  Now with CFFI, you can either do the exact same and then export each of the 34 DLLs to Python, or use the shortcut of doing it only for the `a` library but not for the 33 others.  You can have `set_source` compile custom C code---but this produces a .pyd and not a .dll, with no real control over exported symbols, so it doesn't work for `a`